# using data posted by ajax to node js problem

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, ejs

I'm trying to update my template without refreshing the page by ajax .... and I used two arrays for saving data permanently on front side and I send these two arrays with post method and ajax to my node js... I have some other input in my template but I don't want to send them with ajax ... How to parse them beside
ajax post?

**my server**

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const multer = require("multer");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
var titlesList = [];

app.use(express.static("public"));
//if we wanna recive data from ajax we have to use this line
// var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
// parse application/json
app.use(express.json());// add this line
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var c = [];

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null , "public/upload");
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null , file.filename + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
var upload = multer ({
    storage:storage
})
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/landingDb" , {useNewUrlParser : true} , { useUnifiedTopology: true } );


const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    courseTitle : String,
    courseSubtitle : String,
    coursreAuthor : String,
    coursePrice : Number,
    courseVideo : Object,
    courseSpecs : Array,
    courseTitles : Array,
    courseValidation : Number,
    courseTags : Array

});
const Courses = mongoose.model("Courses" ,courseSchema );



app.set("view engine", "ejs");



app.get("/cp" , function(req , res){
    res.render("cp");
});








app.post("/cp" , upload.single("c_upload")  , function(req , res){



var c_titles = [];

    const c_specs = JSON.stringify(req.body.specs);
    const file = req.file;
    const c_title = req.body.c_title;
    const c_subtitle = req.body.c_subtitle;
    const c_creator = req.body.c_creator;
    const c_price = req.body.c_price;
    console.log(file);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.titles));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));


if(req.body.submitcp == "submitCp"){
    console.log(file);

const courses = new Courses({
    
    
    
courseTitle:c_title,
courseSubtitle:c_subtitle,
courseAuthor : c_creator,
coursePrice : c_price,
courseVideo : file,
courseTitles : c_titles,
courseSpecs : c_specs,
courseValidation : 0

});
courses.save();
}


});



















app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("running");
});
```

**my html**

```
<%- include('header'); -%>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div dir="rtl" class="col-md-6 cp_main_div">
        <form action="/cp" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="titlesForm" id="form" method="post">
            
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">عنوان دوره</label>
                <input name="c_title" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="...">
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">توضیحات مختصر دوره</label>
                <input name="c_subtitle" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="...">
              </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">سازنده دوره</label>
            <input name="c_creator" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="...">
          </div>
        </div>


        
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">قیمت دوره</label>
                <input name="c_price" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="...">
              </div>
            </div>


        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">آپلود ویدیو معرفی</label>
                <input name="c_upload" type="file" class="form-control-file videoup" id="fileupload">
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" >    
            <div class="c_preview_div">
                <div class="video_play"></div>
                <video class="c-preview-video">
                    <source src="assets/gm2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support HTML video.
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">نوع دوره</label>
                <select name="c_type" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    <option>وبینار</option>
                    <option>دوره آنلاین</option>
                    <option>دوره آفلاین</option>
                    <option>ورکشاپ</option>
                    <option>دوره فیزیکی</option>
                </select>              
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="form-group">
                    
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">عنوان های دوره</label>
                    <input  name="titlesInput" id="titlesInp"   type="text" class="form-control cp_input_titles" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="...">
                  </div>
                  <button  id="title_submit" name="addTitles" value="addtitles" type="clickspecs_submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 add_titles">+</button>
                 

                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="showTitles">


                </div>

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">مشخصات دوره</label>
                        <input  name="specsInput" id="c_specs"   type="text" class="form-control cp_input_titles" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="...">
                      </div>
                      <button id="specs_submit" name="addSpecs" value="addspecs" type="click" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 add_titles">+</button>
    
    
                    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="showSpecs">
                        
                    </div>
    
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">تگ ها</label>
                            <select name="c_type" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                                <option>وبینار</option>
                                <option>دوره آنلاین</option>
                                <option>دوره آفلاین</option>
                                <option>ورکشاپ</option>
                                <option>دوره فیزیکی</option>
                            </select>              
                        </div>
                        </div>

                


                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" name="submitcp" value="submitCp" id="submitpostCp" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">send</button>
                </div>
      </div> 
    </form>
    <!-- <iframe id="uploader_iframe" name="uploader_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe> -->

    </div>
    </div>
</div>









</body>


<footer>


</footer>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="sort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightslider.js"></script>


</html>
```

**my ajax call**

```
var titlesLis = [];
var specsLis = [];

document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   //check what btn submit and push to item to array

   if (e.submitter.id == "title_submit") {
      var titlesInp = $(".cp_input_titles").val();
      titlesLis.push(titlesInp);

   }


   //check what btn submit and push to item to array

   if (e.submitter.id == "specs_submit") {
      var specsInp = $("#c_specs").val();
      specsLis.push(specsInp);
   }

   //check what btn submit and remove item from array
   //check what btn submit and delete the item from view
   if (e.submitter.id == "delete_specs") {
      if(e.submitter.id >="0"){
         specsLis.splice(e.submitter.id , 1);
      }
      $("#" + 'specs' + e.submitter.value).remove();
      showspecItems();

   }

   //check what btn submit and remove item from array
   //check what btn submit and delete the item from view
   if (e.submitter.id == "delete_titles") {
      if(e.submitter.id >="0"){
         titlesLis.splice(e.submitter.id , 1);
      }

      $("#" + 'titles' + e.submitter.value).remove();
      showtitleItems();
   }

   var data = {};
   data.titles = titlesLis;
   data.specs = specsLis;


   //ajax call

   $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/cp',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json',
         xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: false
      },
      headers: {

      },
      success: function (data) {
         console.log('Success');
         console.log(data);

         //check what btn submit and delete the item from view
         if (e.submitter.id == "title_submit") {
            showtitleItems();
         }
         if (e.submitter.id == "specs_submit") {
            showspecItems();
         }
      },
      error: function () {
         console.log('We are sorry but our servers are having an issue right now');
      }

   })

   function showtitleItems() {
      $("#showTitles").empty();
      for (var i = 0; titlesLis.length > i; i++) {
         $("#showTitles").append('<div id="' + 'titles' + i + '" class="TSShow titlesShow"><button name="deleteTitles" value="' + i + '" type="submit" id="delete_titles">-</button><h4>' + titlesLis[i] + '</h4></div>');
      }
   }

   function showspecItems() {
      $("#showSpecs").empty();
      for (var i = 0; specsLis.length > i; i++) {
         $("#showSpecs").append('<div id="' + 'specs' + i + '" class="TSShow specsShow"><button name="deleteSpecs" value="' + i + '" type="submitz" id="delete_specs">-</button><h4>' + specsLis[i] + '</h4></div>');
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: what the error you are getting from server?

Comment: @NarendraKumawat i can get data from ajax ... but i can not use them with node js post .....if i use the ajax data with node js post i get undefined error and if i use req.body without node js post i dont have no problem (sorry for my bad english)